# How to Make the IP Address Appear as Part of Bash Prompt?

Tags: bash, hostname, bashrc, prompt

Running an Amazon EC2 instance with Ubuntu 22.04. The elastic ip address is 52.120.94.72.

I want the bash prompt to read like this (no space)

```
della@52.120.94.72:~/working_directory$
```

Based on some advice on the net, I edited the top of the /etc/hosts file like this

```
127.0.0.1 localhost 52.120.94.72
```

and even added the following line to .bashrc

```
export PS1='\[\033[0;32m\]\u@\h:\[\033[36m\]\W\[\033[0m\] \$ '
```

But it is not working, and currently, the bash prompt looks like

```
della@52:~ $
```

which is ridiculous. How to make it appear like I want. Also, is the $HOSTNAME environment variable important in this context? Particularly, if I run some web server in this instance, I can make calls just using the ip address, right? No need for the hostname.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting your prompt actually derive that IP-address is, as far as I know, rather more difficult. Bash does not provide a ready-made variable to use for that according to the list with special characters [here](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt).

I think the easiest is to simply hardcode the IP-address you want to see in your prompt definition:

```
 export PS1='\u@52.120.94.72:\w\$'
```

where `\u`, `\$` and `\w` are some of those special characters that get expanded by your bash shell according to the definitions from [here](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt) :

- **`\u`**
  The username of the current user.
- **`\w`**
  The value of the PWD shell variable (`$PWD`), with `$HOME` abbreviated with a tilde `~` (uses the `$PROMPT_DIRTRIM` variable).
- **`\$`**
  If the effective uid is 0, `#`, otherwise `$`.

With the additional escapes in the example you quoted:

```
 export PS1='\[\033[0;32m\]\u@52.120.94.72:\[\033[36m\]\w\[\033[0m\]\$'
```

you get a prompt formatted with ANSI escape sequences/codes that instruct the terminal program you're using to apply specific formatting and colouring.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences  for a detailed overview.

---

You could of course rely on external helper to derive your IP, such as query the instance meta data URI :

```
MY_IP=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4)
export PS1='\u@$MY_IP:\w\$'
```

Comment: This definitely put me in the right direction - a bit more dynamically, you could use `export ELASTIC_IP=$(curl ipinfo.io/ip)`, then to set it you use `PS1='\u@$ELASTIC_IP:\w\$'`. If you put this in your .bashrc or profile with the export, you also have access to that value throughout your session - `echo $ELASTIC_IP`